# EF Code First Join Table Returning Null Object

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I'm having trouble with an join table i've created in EF Core Code First.

This is my class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FooBar> FooBars { get; set; }
}

public class FooBar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Models.Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Models.Bar Bar { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The problem i'm facing when returning FooBar is that Foo is correctly returning the selected Foo object.  whilst Bar is null.

My query for data is done like this:

```
        var foo = _context.Foo
            .Include(r => r.FooBar)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == message.Id);
```

However, in the database it is correctly setting the ID of bar and looks like this:

SELECT [Id]
      ,[FooId]
      ,[BarId]
      ,[Quantity]
  FROM [dbo].[FooBar]

Id  FooId   Quantity    BarId
1   2   5   2

Examining the Keys on the FooBar table, i can see the following:

- PK_FooBar
- FK_FooBar_Foo_FooId
- FK_FooBar_Bar_BarId

What am i doing wrong that is stopping Bar from being returned?
Nothing is obvious at the moment.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to explicitly load Bar by chaining with ThenInclude. Bar won't be loaded by default because of lazy loading behaviour in entity framework to save potential stackoverflow and only loading what is needed.

Therefore, although Bar is attached to FoorBar but not loaded and hence null.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding a ThenInclude:

```
var foo = _context.Foo
            .Include(r => r.FooBar)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Bar)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == message.Id);
```

Not sure why i have to include the ThenInclude for Bar when Foo was returned.  if anyone has any light on this that would be great.

thanks

Comment: Anyway thats because lazy loading will not load the related object which is Bar unless you explicitly ask for it hence it was null.

Comment: sorry @ChirdeepTomar post your answer and i'll mark it as correct.  cheers mate